# Convert all cout/cin to print to a textbox in GUI

Tags: c++, forms, user-interface, console

Basically I have a complete console application built with cout/cin's everywhere in multiple cpp files. For my application, the cin takes numbers 0-7, thus the gui would have maybe buttons 0-7, etc. The cout would just be replaced by printing onto a textbox on the GUI.

```
cout << "WELCOME TO YOUR PERSONAL FINANCE ACCOUNT SYSTEM" << endl; //MAIN MENUS
cout << "Please Select an account to access: " << endl;
cout << "1. Stock Portfolio Account" << endl;
cout << "2. Bank Account" << endl;
cout << "3. Design Pattern Settings" << endl; // USER CAN PICK DEISGN PATTERNS HERE
cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
int access;

    cin >> access;

switch (access) {
case 1: {

        stockAccount->main_menu(portfolio, bankAccount);

        break; }
case 2: {

        bankAccount->main_menu(portfolio, stockAccount); 




    break; }
case 3: {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Personal Assistor: " << endl;
    cout << "1. OFF: " << endl;
    cout << "2. ON: " << endl;
    cout << endl; cout << endl;

    cout << "Sorting Method: " << endl;
    cout << "3. Selection Sort - Optimal Data Movement: a simple sort. " << endl;
    cout << "4. Insertion Sort: - Optimal for investors who pick stocks near the same value " << endl;


    int choice;
    cin >> choice;
    switch (choice) {
    case 1: {
        acc->assist = false;
        cout << endl;
        cout <<"Personal Assistor Turned OFF "<<endl;
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open("assist.txt");
        fout << "OFF";
        fout.close();
        break; }
    case 2: {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Personal Assistor Turned ON " << endl;
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open("assist.txt");
        fout << "ON";
        fout.close();
        acc->assist = true;
        break; }
    case 3: {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "SORT ALGORITHM: SELECTION SORT" << endl;

        ofstream fout;
        fout.open("sort.txt");
        fout << "sel";
        fout.close();
        break; }
    case 4: {
        cout << endl;
        cout << "SORT ALGORITHM: INSERTION SORT" << endl;
        ofstream fout;
        fout.open("sort.txt");
        fout << "ins";
        fout.close();
        break; }
    }
    main(1);
    return 0;
    break; }
case 4: {
    cout <<"Have a nice day!"<< endl;
    return 0;
    break; }
default: {
    cout <<"Please Enter a Valid Number"<< endl;
    main(1);

}


}
```

ive looked through QT and it was way too difficult with the learning curve (i only need this gui for a short class assignment, not too learn it for own use), professor said to use whatever we want. I looked into windows form. I just need a tutorial telling me exactly this:

1) HERE ARE THE BUTTONS, EACH BUTTON INPUTS A NUMBER

2) IF SAID BUTTON IS PRESSED, OUTPUT STRINGS TO GUI TEXTBOX (output strings to gui textbox - meaning all the couts in multiple .cpp files are printed to the gui textbox as i enter the corresponding numbers/etc.)

Again, its for a short assignment, I don't have the time to thoroughly learn any complicated GUI application development, please let me know if there is any simple example. I understand i have to change the cin/couts, but thats all i want to change. thank you

Comment: There's no simple way to convert from a command line application to a GUI. Writing out to a textbox is probably not enough.

Comment: Do you want to use push buttons or a drop-down list?

Comment: i realized my application also needs to take string inputs, so maybe one input texbox for all inputs would suffice. Ex:

Comment: for example: please enter a stock name, normal i'd cin 'GOOG' for google stock info, and then the info would print with cout, but i just need it to print to a textbox, ive created the a windows form UI just don't know how to program it to connect all the cin/couts to it

Comment: Are you asking for code?  design layout?  This is not a site that provides code or designs for free.

Comment: no not code. I'm saying what would the approach be here. I have 3 files with function definitions and 1 main cpp file that originally ran the console application. Now say i create a MyForms.cpp and myForms.h, I'm asking can i change the "cout" and "cin" throughout my cpp files and essentially link them to the myForms.cpp which is a windows form file. If you know a link to a tutorial that does this it'd be helpful, just need a direction

Answer (score 0):

Create dialog based mfc application from Visual studio.

Its simple, Just drag and drop buttons and text boxes from toolbox at IDE's side. Double clicking on button , will take you to the function that will be executed on that button's click.